# Margins become smaller

Tags: html, css

I want to make left and right margins on my webpage. I make a main div element and set margins

```
<div id = "wrap" style="display: block; margin-left:200px;margin-right:200px;">
...
</div>
```

But when I resize the page in a browser, margins become smaller. However, I need them to be fixed,so if the content size+left margin+ right margin becomes larger than the screen,the scroll bar must appear.

Comment: A http://www.jsfiddle.net with your code will be helpful

Comment: Is the element's width going to be fixed too?

Comment: check mu answer, i hope i help u, thanks to juan too

Comment: Have you tried `min-width:200px`?

Comment: @JuanGuerrero, yes.And the scrollbar should appear in case of lack of space on the screen.

Comment: @jCuber, `min-width` of what?

Comment: @Alex Add `min-width:200px;` to the style of the div. Actually, I made a jsFiddle of your code and it works just fine, are you sure you don't have another style with percentages measuring the margins?: http://jsfiddle.net/fGM2w/1/

Comment: After looking at your page, I think there are more things involved that what you think. Floating an element makes it get out of parent flow (that's why `wrap` div has 0 height). Add `overflow: auto` to `wrap`. This forces the browser to recalculate sizes. That way, the margins stay.

Finally, add overflow: auto to the elements you want to have an scrollbar and checkout @jCuber advice about percentages and things like that.

Comment: @Alex Glad to hear that. But I would also take a look about all those `floats` and `overflow:hidden` that you have around. They aren't necessary always and in CSS, the less properties and combinations, the better.

Comment: @JuanGuerrero, ok, thanks for your advices, I'll try to play with it.

Comment: look at it
<div id="wrap" style="min-width: 950px;display: block; position: relative; width: 100%;padding-right: 150px;padding-left: 150px;">

Answer (score 0):

try

```
margin-left:200px!important;margin-right:200px!important;
```

and thry to apply

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
   }
```

Comment: I believe you're too hasty with using the `!important` keyword which is a bad practice. It's more advisable to help to OP find his real problem / overriding classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrap" style="min-width: 950px;display: block; position: relative; padding-right: 150px;padding-left: 150px;">
```

try this code

u set margins, i set absolute position, so left and right must be 200px anyway!
or just add to ur style overflow:auto

```
    <div id="wrap" style="display: block; margin-left:200px;margin-right:200px;overflow: auto;">
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
.............
</div>
```

and with position absolute

```
<div id="wrap" style="display: block; position: absolute;left: 200px;right: 200px;background: black;color: white;"> ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. ................. </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain what's this supposed to be.

Comment: Im bad english, but, i just make a margin, that appear in browser.
and u needed to set position absolute and set up position where it need to appear

Comment: This doesn't work in his situation, as it seems he wants some sort of `overflow: auto`

Comment: This work, but by other way, u way just more simple. but thanks for advice, edited

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work! See http://www.sapa.su/test_page.html
When you resize your brouser screen the right margin disapears.

Comment: @MichałSzałapski 'overflow: auto;' works not in the way I want.Margins are fixed but they overlay the content and a scrollbar doesn't appear.

Comment: i think i dont understand u:/
try it
<div id="wrap" style="min-width: 950px;display: block; position: relative;  /* margin: 0 auto; *//* width: 100%; */padding-right: 150px;padding-left: 150px;">

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using javascript. Maybe it's not a best one,but it works. In **onload** and **onresize** event handlers I type

```
var content_width = 960;                
var window_width = parseFloat($(window).width());

var margin_perc = 0.141;     
var margin_width =window_width*margin_perc;

var w = (content_width+margin_width).toString()+"px";

$("#top").css("width",w);
$("#top").css("margin-right",(margin_width).toString()+"px");

$("#top").css("margin-left",(margin_width).toString()+"px");
```

Also I align styles for **body** element and block **"wrap"**:

```
<body id="top" style = " width: 960px;margin-left:100px;margin-right:100px;
overflow: auto;position: absolute;">

<div id = "wrap" style="width: 960px;display: block;">
...
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks, to all for help!